# Como funciona o módulo sys do python e para que ele serve?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou acompanhando um livro, e não estou conseguindo entender uma parte sobre Parâmetros de linha de comando, nesta pagina ele esta utilizando o módulo sys e trabalhando com a lista arqv:

```
import sys 

print(f"Número de parâmetros: {len(sys.argv)}")
for n, p in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print(f"Parâmetro {n} = {p}")
```

Ele usa este metodo em varios exercícios seguintes e basicamente você precisa aprender a usar sys, apenas com essa explicação acima;

LIVRO: Introdução à Programação com Python 3ª Edição - 2019 = Pag. 198

Comment: Serve para muitas coisas, basicamente é uma lib com diversas funções voltadas principalmente para trabalhar com as "configurações" obtidas na execução atual de um script, por exemplo, pegar parametros, pegar variaveis de ambiente, pegar caminho do script ou de onde esta sendo executado, fora que proporciona algum controle na interface de linha de comando, o que pode variar pelo tipo de interface ou terminal. Devem haver "palavras" técnicas exatas neste tal livro, mas no geral é isto.

Comment: Poderia me explicar como funciona o programa que anexei na pergunta, não consegui entender, ou agum lugar que eu possa entender mais sobre o módulo sys.

Comment: Sua duvida é só sobre o `sys.argv` ou é também sobre a linguagem Python e como funciona o `for`? Porque esta me parecendo que você não tem familiaridade com a linguagem (talvez), ai a explicação pode ir além.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O módulo `sys` fornece funções e variáveis ​​usadas para manipular diferentes partes do ambiente de tempo de execução do Python e apesar de serem completamente diferentes, muitas pessoas confundem o módulo `sys` e o módulo `os` (módulo para manipular o sistema operacional).

Com o módulo `sys` você pode por exemplo, saber qual a plataforma do dispositivo que está rodando o seu código, obter os caminhos de sistema que o interpretador Python utiliza, módulos importados, versão do Python, entre outros.

---

**O que é sys.argv ?**

O `sys.argv` não é um método, ele é uma lista que guarda os parâmetros passados na execução do seu código Python, sendo o primeiro elemento o caminho do seu código. Exemplo:

```
// arquivo.py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Agora execute esse código no seu terminal passando alguns valores, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
> arquivo.py param1 param2 param3
```

A saída disso será:

```
['C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\exemplo\\arquivo.py','param1','param2','param3']
```

Como pudemos ver acima, o `sys.argv` é muito útil pois podemos configurar o programa externamente ou então passar dados como email, senha e outros para dentro dele, mesmo depois de ter compilado ou gerado um executável do código.

Answer (score 4):

O módulo `sys` do Python contém algumas variáveis e funções relacionadas ao funcionamento do próprio Python no ambiente em que ele está rodando.

Então na verdade, cada coisa dentro do `sys` tem papéis muito diferentes - tem funções que retornam o limite máximo de recursão do Python - o que só tem a ver com a linguagem (`sysgetrecusionlimit()`). Tem funções que retornam a codificação de acentos usada por padrão em arquivos de texto (`sys.getdefaultencoding`). Tem funções para encerrar o programa imediatamente, de onde esti ver (`sys.exit()`) - tem variáveis preenchidas automaticamente com informações sobre a última exceção que aconteceu no programa (`sys.exc_info`)  - Em suma, muita coisa, a maioria de uso avançado - e a única forma de saber "pra que serve" cada coisa é ver a documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Já a variável `sys.argv` é uma das mais usadas e mais simples de explicar -e, assim como tudo o mais no `sys`, não está relacionada com outras coisas no módulo.

`sys.argv` é uma lista de strings que tem os parâmetros passados na linha de comando para iniciar seu programa.

Então, se o seu programa foi iniciado no terminal com o comando:

`python meuprograma.py aquelearquivo.txt 2` , a variável `sys.argv` vai ser uma lista com as strings `["meuprograma.py", "aquelearquivo.txt", "2"]`  (note que todos os elementos sao sempre strings, mesmo o '2' sendo numérico). COm isso o Python permite que qualquer código simples interaja com os parâmeros passados pela linha de comando, além de trazer um nome famíliar a quem programa em `C`, onde esses parâmetros ficam disponíveis para a função `main` na forma de um vetor de ponteiros para strings: `char **argv` - sendo que, em C, a contagem de argumentos tem que vir num parâmetro separado - `int argc`. Essa contagem não é necessária em Python por que os argumentos já vem como uma lista de Python, que "sabe" o seu comprimento.

POr fim, um outro diferencial do `sys` é que assim que o Python é iniciado, ele já é importado automaticamente - ele não é lido separadamente do disco. Para o programador Python, isso não é perceptível, ele tem que ser importado como qualquer outro módulo - mas isso é apenas para disponibilizar o nome "sys"  como uma variável que possa ser usada. Internamente, se vocẽ tem só o `python.exe` no Windows, por exemplo, e nenhum arquivo de biblioteca, mesmo assim vai poder usar o módulo `sys`.

Answer (score 1):

O módulo sys permite usar stdin() e stdout(), bem como stderr(), mas, mais interessante, podemos utilizar o sys.argv () . Para muitos, esse é um conceito confuso, mas é bastante simples e muito útil quando você o aprende. A ideia do sys.argv é permitir que você passe argumentos para o Python a partir da linha de comando.

Essa capacidade atua como uma ponte para a capacidade de comunicação entre Python e outras linguagens, que podem se comunicar novamente através do shell para interagir.

Com stdout e stdin, podemos passar mensagens e erros para a linha de comando ou apenas usá-los para fins de registro.

Permite uma interação com o sistema do Python:

```
exit() - sair do modo interativo do Python!
```

```
argv - acesso a linha de comandos
```

```
path - acesso ao path do sistema
```

```
ps1 - para mudar '>>>' prompt do Python!
```